# Change the date format at the header - NGX-Print

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I'm using at my application the ngx-print with angular 8.
when I click print-button, it added at the header a date,  with format mm/dd/yy. 
I want to change that to dd/mm/yy.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any documentation for it.

[image]

I tried to understand the source code: https://github.com/selemxmn/ngx-print 
without success.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi @elior did you found the solution ? I have a similar requirement, but not getting any solution to change the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Actually date you are getting while printing is because header and footer option is checked in browser's printing popup under the **more setting** option.And for custom date as per requirement you have to pass that **manually** with your object.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your answer by providing an example and/or more detailed steps to how you would solve the question. Thank you